# System volume linked with ringtone volume

Tags: android, volume, ringtone

Is there any way to check if system volume is linked with ringtone volume?

Comment: did you find a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way would be to store the values for the system volume and ringtone volume, then change the system volume and compare the ringtone volume with the earlier stored value to see if there was any change in it (If the values are different, that means the system and ringtone volumes are linked). After that you can just restore the volumes to the earlier values again.